# Laravel - Displaying value based on option in select form element

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my controller

```
 if ($request->get('name')){
           dd( "good");}
```

This is my blade file

```
<select name="sort" form="order">

            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="dateAdded">Date added</option>
```

But the controller is not geting the select form element, please what am i doing wrong

Comment: May be this is not possible so you are use (i.e if ($request->get('sort')){
           dd( "good");}) and try

Comment: Please can you rephrase your answer

Comment: Pelase check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing select-option value instead of select-name.

```
if ($request->get('sort'))
{
   dd( "good");
}
```

If you wan't to show message only if **name** option is selected.

```
if ($request->get('sort')=="name")
{
   dd( "good");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this and access in your function:

```
 if ($request->get('sort')){
           dd( "good");}
```

Comment: Please How will i access in my function

Comment: $request->get('sort') through

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it as the following:

```
if ($request->input('sort'))
{
 dd( "good");
}else{
 dd( "bad");
}
```

or

```
if ($request->sort)
{
 dd( "good");
}else{
 dd( "bad");
}
```

or

```
if ($request->has('sort'))
{
 dd( "good");
}else{
 dd( "bad");
}
```